# Could anybody point out the mistake I am doing in this perl program?

Tags: regex, perl

As per the below code I should get `bibhu` printed once and `j` should be 1 if I  enter "bibhu" at runtime. But It's not happening. Why am I getting `j=0`?

```
print "enter\n";
$find=<STDIN>;
$j=0;
@lines=qw(bibhu prasanna behera kuni shun jbjdkj);    
foreach (@lines) {
    if ($_ =~ /$find/) {
        print "$_\n";
        $j=$j+1;
    }
}
print "$j\n";
```

Comment: What result would you expect if your array contained `foobibhubar`? Your current program would return a match

Answer (score 7):

You need to strip the newline from the input, just call [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html):

```
chomp($find = <STDIN>);
```

Without that, if you enter "bibhu" at the prompt, `$find` will be equal to `"bibhu\n"`.

Answer (score 1):

Here a slightly improved version of your script - as Lucas T. has written, you need to remove the newline at the end of entered string with [chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

print "enter\n";
chomp(my $find=(<STDIN>));
my $j=0;
my @lines=qw(bibhu prasanna behera kuni shun jbjdkj);    
foreach (@lines) {
    if (/$find/o) {
        print "$_\n";
        $j=$j+1;
    }
}
print "$j\n";
```

Comment: Please avoid `-w` on the command line or shebang. `use warnings` is much preferred, and `use warnings 'all'` ideal. I personally like `use warnings qw/ all FATAL /` which will also kill the program if any warning is encountered

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking the other way round: You can add a `\n` to your `$_` in the `if`:

```
...
if ("$_\n" =~ /$find/) {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is your input contain with the newline character. So you should remove the newline from input or your regex to allow the newline.

Remove the newline from a input use `chomp` as mentioned other answer.

The other way is you should use [x flag](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#/x) flag for to allow the whitespace or newline in your regex.

```
print "enter\n";
$find=<STDIN>;
$j=0;
@lines=qw(bibhu prasanna behera kuni shun jbjdkj);    
foreach (@lines) {
    if ($_ =~ /$find/x) {
    print "$_\n";
    $j=$j+1;
    }
}
print "$j\n";
```

**But better you use chomp**